# How to use memorystore session in JS message worker

Tags: javascript, node.js, message-queue, worker, google-cloud-memorystore

I am trying to use `google-clound-memorystore` to save some values in a session. Later I would like to use this session(memorystore based) in different message queue workers build in nodeJS.

Is there any **`library or package`** available in JS which can be use inside a message worker to fetch and update session values?

A code snippet would also help.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to check on these two post in github [rsmq-worker](https://github.com/mpneuried/rsmq-worker) and [redis-smq](https://github.com/weyoss/redis-smq)?

Comment: Thanks for sharing but I think they are redis based message queues. I have message queue implemented via google-pubsub but I need to know how can I access session values in different workers(implemented via google pubsub)?
There are couple libraries for express sessions but is there anything for non-express one?